# Automate drawing lines between multiple objects illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, automation

I would like to be able to connect multiple objects to the same point using some sort of automated routine.

Say I have 20 squares and I want to draw an arrow between each square and another point, without having to create 20 lines manually.

This is something like what I want to do (circle I1 is connected to all the circles in the next row):

[image]

Comment: You could script this.

Comment: sorry, I don't know anything about scripting... at what point would learning scripting and designing this routine be faster than just doing it manually?